# ¿Como hacer para que el texto del menu quede de un color cuando está en foco?

Tags: php, css, bootstrap, navbar, hover

Basicamente es un menu que el texto tiene un color, y quiero que cada vez que se va cambiando de pagina, quede de otro color el texto del menú de esa pagina en la cual estoy parado. Intente con un :focus pero no me funcionó. No se si hay alguna otra manera con php y bootstrap.

Este es mi menu:

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-start justify-content-md-end" id="menu-fijo">                          
            <ul class="w-75 navbar-nav justify-content-around">                       
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.php?s=home" data-ancla="true" data-freno="60">Home</a></li>  
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.php?s=productos" data-ancla="true" data-freno="60">Productos</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.php?s=contacto" data-ancla="true" data-freno="60">Contacto</a></li>                                                                          
            </ul>                                            
        </div>
```

Gracias, espero que puedan ayudarme.

Edit: Me referia a un :focus, no un :hover, ahi lo cambié. Basicamente es lo que decia, tengo 3 secciones (home, productos, contacto), las 3 por defecto estan en color gris oscuro, pero quiero que que quede en blanco una siempre, que sea la de la seccion en la que esté parado.

Comment: En el HTML de cada página tendrías que cambiar el color del elemento correspondiente.

Comment: Aunque la pregunta no me queda del todo clara. ¿Quieres que el color cambie cuando el cursor se posiciona encima de cada link, o que cambie el color del link correspondiente a la página actual?

Comment: @Fedex7501 No, perdon me referia a los :focus, no al :hover. Ahi lo modifique y agregue un poco mas de info para explicarlo mejor. Despues no es tema de hacer cambios en cada html porque uso una pagina maestra con un header unico (no duplicado).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar `$_GET['']` y comprobar en cada caso el valor que recibes en la variable `s` que le pasas al index cada vez que haces click en uno, por lo que podrias probar a crear algo parecido a esto:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['s'])){  

   if($_GET['s'] == 'home'){
     echo '<li class="nav-item"><a style="color:red" class="nav-link" href="index.php?s=home" data-ancla="true" data-freno="60">Home</a></li>' ;
   }else{
     echo '<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.php?s=home" data-ancla="true" data-freno="60">Home</a></li>';
   }
 }
?>
```

Y ahí podras añadir todas las que necesites. También deberás de adaptar lo que te he puesto a tu código, y añadir todos los enlaces, ya que solo lo he puesto para el primero